# Do I need an IP address?

Tags: networking, network-programming

I want to send data within a WLAN as fast as possible to another device within this WLAN? And I am completely confused at the moment.

If I want to send something from one device in this WLAN to another device in this WLAN. Do I necessarily need an IP Address then?

So I could write a program that produces IP Packets and sends them to the destination. Then I would program at Network layer.

Can I go to the data linklayer and send something to the Router in this WLAN and he figures out where to send it without any ip address? Would it be faster than programming at Network layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could indeed sent to the MAC address. Bit I doubt if it's worth the effort. Using IP is the standard way of doing things. Speed would only improve minimally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need IP address in both devices if you are using TCP/IP stack.

You can directly send with the MAC address without IP if you are under the same lan switch. Use raw sockets. This is not recommended.